# Why my site getting soft 404 errors from search term on 404 page showing in GWT?

Tags: web-crawler, google-search-console

I just recently switched to the wordpress and I’m suddenly getting a couple of soft 404 errors on Google Webmaster tools.

I think they are all coming from the somehow automatic search or getting crawled by Google within coding of our wordpress website on the NOT FOUND page since that’s the

only search page I have found, they all have the term {search_term} as the search query and the page gives me a “Nothing Found” result.

I would love to hear some advice on how to resolve this issue.

This is what I see on the webmaster tool, also check [screenshot link here](https://08875344305734164866.googlegroups.com/attach/2b96e5e59fa065a4/errors1.jpg?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrFKZV8CPHBebRUzhVqASY8KZxeKHzgNm1Pkii6gXMQ7-Mw8VMAQLICfAWnOOF5c83PL7oKFU2JTxq5-h9zj3_cc1ZUj90zsPOK0jSy2ADQyEhn_hPk).

Soft 404
Url: abc.com/search/%7Bsearch_term%7D/

Linked from
abc.com/search/{search_term}/
abc.com/?s=%7Bsearch_term%7D

Thank you,
Ram Babu

Answer (score 0):

I see you've posted this elsewhere on the web too, but seeing as I've had this problem for some time - I figured it might be useful to others to post an answer here.

Also found online was the following code, which creates a virtual `robots.txt` file, blocking the crawlers from accessing the non-existent `/search/` pages which aren't returning a 404:

```
// WordPress Virtual robots.txt additions
add_filter( 'robots_txt', 'v_robots', 10, 2 );

function v_robots( $output, $public ) {
$output .= "Disallow: /search/" . "\n";
return $output;
}
```